# Random Permutation of Rows of a Large Dataset

Tags: sas, permutation, enterprise-guide

I need to create a random permutation of a data set with over 3 million rows.

I have tried to use PROC PLAN, based off of this example: http://support.sas.com/kb/23/977.html According to this article, having n = (number of rows)! allows the random selection of a permutation. Unfortunately for a set this size, that is 4.3*10^19668676 permutations. Obviously I run into a bit of a memory problem here.

I also found an example using PROC IML, but it looks like my company does not have the necessary licence/software package to use it.

Can anyone supply me with a good way to shuffle this data set?

Comment: If you have some way of giving each data row a unique index then you could use the [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) to generate indexes to the data. I take it that you only want a small quantity of permutations rather than all of them.

Comment: You say random permutation? Can you provide more information? A part of me wants to say PROC SURVEYSELECT with SRS, but not certain for sure.

Comment: Right - how is 'random permutation' different from 'random sample [without replacement]'?

Comment: Apologies for not responding sooner. @AndrewMorton, I was looking at exactly the Fisher-Yates shuffle, but I have no idea how to do it in SAS.

Comment: @Joe You can't really call it a sample since I want the entire set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to take the rows and put them in a random order.  If so, the most common method is to create a random value for each row and then sort by the random values:

```
DATA augmented ;
  SET original ;
  sortval = RAND('UNIFORM') ;
RUN ;

PROC SORT DATA=augmented OUT=permuted(DROP=sortval) ;
  BY sortval ;
RUN ;
```

You can use the CALL STREAMINIT(seedval) call routine if you want to be able to precisely reproduce the random sequence at a later time.

You could also probably do this with PROC SQL [untested code]:

```
PROC SQL ;
  CREATE TABLE permuted(DROP=sortval) AS
    SELECT a.*, RAND('UNIFORM') AS sortval
      FROM original a
      ORDER BY sortval
  ;
QUIT ;
```

Comment: The only problem I see here is that RAND( 'UNIFORM' ) repeats 1,000+ times at this number of rows. Any suggestions on how to correct that?

Comment: It repeats one per row, which seems like it is desired.  It isn't randomize get anything - it's just placing a single pseudorandom number on each row (one row per call).

Comment: @Joe, Sorry, I was unclear. The values that RAND( 'UNIFORM' ) creates are not unique. There are over 1000 values which occur more than once.

Comment: It must be a rounding issue, as the period of the generator is supposed to be (2^31)-1 [see the docs for CALL STREAMINIT].  Add a second random value, sort nesting the second value as a tie breaker.

Comment: For your code in PROC SQL, is there any way to use STREAMINIT?

Comment: %SYSCALL(STREAMINIT(seedval));

Answer (score 2):

Similar to what Ludwig61 said, I would do the following

```
DATA augmented ;
  SET original ;
  call streaminit(12072015)*optional, if you want to set a seed;
  sortval1 = RAND('UNIFORM') ; 
  sortval2 = RAND('UNIFORM') ;
  sortval3 = RAND('UNIFORM') ;
RUN ;

PROC SORT DATA=augmented OUT=permuted(DROP=sortval1 sortval2 sortval3) ;
  BY sortval1 sortval2 sortval3;
RUN ;
```

Since you would run into collisions by just using one random number, you can just add more random numbers until you feel comfortable knowing that you won't get any repeat values, then sort by those random numbers. Given that the Rand('Uniform') function has a period of 2^19937-1, you should be fine using 3--your only enemy in this case is SAS's truncation after 53 bits.

Answer (score 1):

This will create a random shuffle of the data and save the random number seed both as a column in the data and as meta data.  You could omit one or both but I like to let SAS generate the seed and let me save it so I can reproduce the sample/shuffle.  Use a VIEW so the observations are piped directly to PROC SORT.

```
data shuffle / view=shuffle;
   obs = _n_;
   set sashelp.cars;
   if _n_ eq 1 then call streaminit(0);
   r = rand('uniform');
   retain seed;
   if _n_ eq 1 then seed=symgetn('sysrandom');
   run;


proc sort data=shuffle out=shuffle01;
   by r;
   run;
%put NOTE: &=sysrandom;

proc datasets nolist;
   modify shuffle01(label="SEED=&sysrandom");
   run;
   quit;
proc contents;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```